# problem creating Maven Web Project project in netbeans 8.2

Tags: java, maven

I went to New Project > Maven > Web Application and tried creating a maven project. I am using glassfish server 4.1.1 and java EE 7 Web. when i click on finish I get this error.

> cd D:\NetbeansProjects; "JAVA_HOME=C:\Program
> Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_121\jre" cmd /c """C:\Program
> Files\NetBeans 8.2\java\maven\bin\mvn.bat"
> -DarchetypeGroupId=org.codehaus.mojo.archetypes -DarchetypeArtifactId=webapp-javaee7 -DarchetypeVersion=1.1 -DarchetypeRepository=http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 -DgroupId=com.org.nepmart -DartifactId=mavenproject2 -Dversion=1.0-SNAPSHOT -Dpackage=com.org.nepmart.mavenproject2 -Dbasedir=D:\NetbeansProjects -Darchetype.interactive=false -Dmaven.ext.class.path="C:\Program Files\NetBeans 8.2\java\maven-nblib\netbeans-eventspy.jar" --batch-mode archetype:generate"" Scanning for projects... Downloading:
> http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-clean-plugin/2.4.1/maven-clean-plugin-2.4.1.pom
> Failed to retrieve plugin descriptor for
> org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:2.4.1: Plugin
> org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:2.4.1 or one of its
> dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor
> for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:jar:2.4.1 Downloading:
> http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-install-plugin/2.3.1/maven-install-plugin-2.3.1.pom
> Failed to retrieve plugin descriptor for
> org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-install-plugin:2.3.1: Plugin
> org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-install-plugin:2.3.1 or one of its
> dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor
> for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-install-plugin:jar:2.3.1
> Downloading:
> http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-deploy-plugin/2.7/maven-deploy-plugin-2.7.pom
> Failed to retrieve plugin descriptor for
> org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:2.7: Plugin
> org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:2.7 or one of its
> dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor
> for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:jar:2.7 Downloading:
> http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-site-plugin/3.0/maven-site-plugin-3.0.pom
> Failed to retrieve plugin descriptor for
> org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-site-plugin:3.0: Plugin
> org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-site-plugin:3.0 or one of its
> dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor
> for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-site-plugin:jar:3.0 Downloading:
> http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-antrun-plugin/1.3/maven-antrun-plugin-1.3.pom
> Failed to retrieve plugin descriptor for
> org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-antrun-plugin:1.3: Plugin
> org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-antrun-plugin:1.3 or one of its
> dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor
> for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-antrun-plugin:jar:1.3 Downloading:
> http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/2.2-beta-5/maven-assembly-plugin-2.2-beta-5.pom
> Failed to retrieve plugin descriptor for
> org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-assembly-plugin:2.2-beta-5: Plugin
> org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-assembly-plugin:2.2-beta-5 or one of
> its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact
> descriptor for
> org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-assembly-plugin:jar:2.2-beta-5
> Downloading:
> http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/2.1/maven-dependency-plugin-2.1.pom
> Failed to retrieve plugin descriptor for
> org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:2.1: Plugin
> org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:2.1 or one of its
> dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor
> for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin:jar:2.1
> Downloading:
> http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-release-plugin/2.0/maven-release-plugin-2.0.pom
> Failed to retrieve plugin descriptor for
> org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-release-plugin:2.0: Plugin
> org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-release-plugin:2.0 or one of its
> dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor
> for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-release-plugin:jar:2.0 Downloading:
> http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/codehaus/mojo/maven-metadata.xml
> Downloading:
> http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-metadata.xml
> Could not transfer metadata
> org.apache.maven.plugins/maven-metadata.xml from/to central
> (http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): Failed to transfer file:
> http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-metadata.xml.
> Return code is: 501 , ReasonPhrase:HTTPS Required. Could not transfer
> metadata org.codehaus.mojo/maven-metadata.xml from/to central
> (http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): Failed to transfer file:
> http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/codehaus/mojo/maven-metadata.xml.
> Return code is: 501 , ReasonPhrase:HTTPS Required. Failure to transfer
> org.apache.maven.plugins/maven-metadata.xml from
> http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local
> repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update
> interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced. Original error:
> Could not transfer metadata
> org.apache.maven.plugins/maven-metadata.xml from/to central
> (http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): Failed to transfer file:
> http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-metadata.xml.
> Return code is: 501 , ReasonPhrase:HTTPS Required. Failure to transfer
> org.codehaus.mojo/maven-metadata.xml from
> http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local
> repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update
> interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced. Original error:
> Could not transfer metadata org.codehaus.mojo/maven-metadata.xml
> from/to central (http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): Failed to
> transfer file:
> http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/codehaus/mojo/maven-metadata.xml.
> Return code is: 501 , ReasonPhrase:HTTPS Required.
> ------------------------------------------------------------------------ BUILD FAILURE
> ------------------------------------------------------------------------ Total time: 7.510s Finished at: Thu Sep 10 16:15:21 NPT 2020 Final
> Memory: 6M/62M
> ------------------------------------------------------------------------ No plugin found for prefix 'archetype' in the current project and in
> the plugin groups [org.apache.maven.plugins, org.codehaus.mojo]
> available from the repositories [local (C:\Users\Aashish
> Katwal.m2\repository), central (http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2)]
> -> [Help 1]
>
> To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e
> switch. Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
>
> For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please
> read the following articles: [Help 1]
> http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/NoPluginFoundForPrefixException

Some body please help!!!

Answer (score 0):

I suspect it's `https` issue, you could try adding this to `pom.xml`:

(after `<packaging>`...`</packaging>` tags)

```
  <pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
        <id>central</id>
        <name>Central Repository</name>
        <url>https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2</url>
        <layout>default</layout>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
        </snapshots>
        <releases>
            <updatePolicy>never</updatePolicy>
        </releases>
    </pluginRepository>
</pluginRepositories>
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>central</id>
        <name>Central Repository</name>
        <url>https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2</url>
        <layout>default</layout>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </repository>
</repositories>
```

Comment: you didn't get my question. I said "Problem Creating Maven Web Project" which means the project is not being created. How can I access pom.xml when the project is not being created 

Comment: or you can add that same xml to your mvn settings.xml. it does not have to be in the pom.xml. and he is right this is "http" issue, strange why they did not just redirect to https and rather give 501, such a friendly response for everyone :D somebody send them medal

Comment: @Aashish have you tried adding the above to maven's settings.xml then?